# input dropdown menu doesn't bind with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I add a task, then click edit, the priority dropdown menu isn't render. I wonder what's is wrong. Take a look my full code here
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3801/

it appear to be `{{task.priorty}}`, not rending with ng-model?

Comment: You should have added some code here as well. The link alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the second drop-down

```
<select ng-show="editable" ng-model="task.priorty" ng-options="priority.level as priority.level for priority in priority">
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3804/)

You needed to add the model of the selected `task` to the edit drop-down list. Also, you had to specify that the value of each item in the edit drop-down is the `level` property.

In the first drop-down, you are selecting the entire `priority` object as the value of each drop-down. However, you only assigned the `priority.level` to `task` (and not the entire `priority` object). Hence, in the edit drop-down, the `priority.level as...` specifies that you are trying to match the `level` property alone with your model.

Comment: it work but the ng-options is so confusing. could you explain that to me? :D

Comment: I added some explanation to answer.

Comment: I seldom see the usage of 'as' in javascript, is this for angular only? I don't get the 'as', I know 'for' means looping..

Comment: Yes, it is in the documentation [AngularJS select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) `select as label for value in array`

Comment: Assuming priority also had an `id` and you wanted to only store the `id` property in `task` while displaying the `level` property in the drop-down. You could then say `p.id as p.level for p in priority`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add ng-Model to your second select (without ngModel your select control won't work).

**Example:**

```
<select ng-show="editable" ng-model="selected_priority2" ng-options="priority.level for priority in priority">
  <option value="">{{tasks.priorty}}</option>
</select>
```

Updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/euvSj/1/)

Comment: that's strange, you tried adding ngModel to your second select?